# Puppeteer: How to get text from a H1class

Tags: puppeteer

I'm trying to get the text from this html but its not working. Can you help me solve this? thanks

**html:**

```
<h1 class="sc-ebzWDT igyUpb" data-test-id="issue.views.issue-base.foundation.summary.heading">
```

Login Test

**code:**

```
element = await page.waitForSelector("[sc-ebzWDT igyUpb]");
title = await page.evaluate(element => element.textContent, element);
```

**error:**

> (node:4948) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Evaluation failed: DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '[sc-ebzWDT igyUpb]' is not a valid selector.

Comment: I guess that the value of the class is dynamic that why the selector is not valid. Can you try to console.log pageContent?

Comment: Could it be that it has a blank space on its id (sc-ebzWDT igyUpb)?

Comment: let try with mode headless = false and view page source on Chromium to check the value of class

Comment: I've opened the page source code and searched for the name but it's not there. Is there a way to find the innertext for dynamic classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's an incorrect selector for a class name, try:

```js
element = await page.waitForSelector(".sc-ebzWDT.igyUpb]");
title = await page.evaluate(element => element.textContent, element);
```

You can read more about CSS Selectors [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors).

Comment: @CesarMsk glad I could help. please accept the answer if it's a solution to your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers